# The equivalent of "examine mode" in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, vrml

How is "examine" mode enabled in an A-Frame scene?

This is the mode that the Visual Inspector uses to browse through the scene and it is also the mode used in [this showcase example](https://d1vlj71acq3rf7.cloudfront.net/index.html).

VRML had the [NavigationInfo](http://graphcomp.com/info/specs/sgi/vrml/spec/part1/nodesRef.html#NavigationInfo) node which provided three viewing modes (through the `type` attribute): Walk, Fly, Examine.

A-Frame provides the ["wasd-controls component"](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/wasd-controls.html#sidebar) which has an attribute `fly` (this basically implies two modes: Fly, Walk) and the ["look-controls component"](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/look-controls.html#sidebar) which could be used to control a scene's orientation (?)

It is not entirely clear if it is possible to enter "examine" mode via a scene attribute (or "mode") or if this is something that has to be implemented via a code snippet (?)

What does "examine" mode look like in A-Frame?

Comment: I would appreciate a bit of clarification around the "-1" vote in this question (?). Apart from describing the scene, VRML also contained nodes on specifying how the scene is to be perceived. Functionality that is shared by A-Frame...so where is the "-1" worthy sin there?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the Three.js OrbitControls, setting the target of the control to the center of the object to be examined?

Comment: @LeeStemkoski Thank you, this is along the right track I think, but would it be "best practice" from the point of view of A-Frame? I appreciate that its focus is VR and in VR an "orbit camera" does not make much sense but still, it is a useful mode of interaction. Isn't there a way of enabling it from a scene attribute rather than having to explicitly write code for it?